# Simple Postgresql libpq code too slow?

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, libpq

I was working on postgresql using libpq. The code given below is taking a lot of time (timings given at the end of code).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <windows.h>

static void exit_nicely(PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    exit(1);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const TCHAR *conninfo;
    PGconn     *conn;
    PGresult   *res;
    int nFields, i, j;

    if (argc > 1)
        conninfo = argv[1];
    else
        conninfo = _T("hostaddr=192.168.4.171 port=12345 dbname=mydb user=myname password=mypass");

    conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
                PQerrorMessage(conn));
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /* Start a transaction block */
    res = PQexec(conn, "BEGIN");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BEGIN command failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    TCHAR szVal1[200];
    TCHAR szVal2[200];
    TCHAR szBuffer[200];

    TCHAR *paramValues[2];
    int paramLengths[2];
    int paramFormats[2] = {0,0};

    ExecStatusType eStatus;

    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    double dAppFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    LONGLONG siStartCounter = li.QuadPart;

    TCHAR szStmt[512] = {0};
    _tcscpy_s(szStmt, 512, _T("Insert50k"));
    Oid oidTypes[2] = {0,0};

    PGresult *pRes =    PQprepare(conn,
                        szStmt,
                        _T("insert into details values($1,$2);"),
                        2,
                        oidTypes);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    LONGLONG siEndCounter = li.QuadPart;
    LONGLONG siLoop = 0;

    double dDiff = (siEndCounter - siStartCounter)/dAppFreq;
    printf("Prepared %.2lf\n", dDiff);

    for(int i=0; i<50000; i++)
    {
        _stprintf_s(szVal1, 200, _T("%d"), i);
        _stprintf_s(szVal2, 200, _T("Detail%d"), i);

        paramValues[0] = szVal1;
        paramValues[1] = szVal2;

        paramLengths[0] = _tcslen(szVal1);
        paramLengths[1] = _tcslen(szVal2);

        siStartCounter = siEndCounter;
        pRes = PQexecPrepared(conn,
                         szStmt,
                         2,
                         paramValues,
                         paramLengths,
                         paramFormats,
                         0);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        siEndCounter = li.QuadPart;
        siLoop += (siEndCounter - siStartCounter);

        eStatus = PQresultStatus(res);
        if (!res ||  (eStatus != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) )
        {
            PQclear(res);
            exit_nicely(conn);
        } 
    }

    dDiff = siLoop/dAppFreq;
    printf("Inserted %.2lf\n", dDiff);

    siStartCounter = siEndCounter;


    _tcscpy_s(szBuffer,200, _T("select count(*) from programdetails;"));
    res = PQexec(conn, szBuffer);

    eStatus = PQresultStatus(res);
    if (!res ||  (eStatus != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) )
    {
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /* first, print out the attribute names */
    nFields = PQnfields(res);
    for (i = 0; i < nFields; i++)
        printf("%-15s", PQfname(res, i));
    printf("\n\n");

    /* next, print out the rows */
    for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nFields; j++)
            printf("%-15s", PQgetvalue(res, i, j));
        printf("\n");
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    siEndCounter = li.QuadPart;
    dDiff = (siEndCounter - siStartCounter)/dAppFreq;
    printf("Printed %.2lf\n", dDiff);

    /* end the transaction */
    res = PQexec(conn, "COMMIT");
    PQclear(res);

    /* close the connection to the database and cleanup */
    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample output (in msecs):

```
Prepared 0.55
Inserted 5527.52
count

50000
Printed 7.58
```

The query here is prepared first, and then executed. This simple insertion takes about 5.5 seconds. Is there a better way to do the same or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You just try to send 50000 requests, that's quite normal ! Perhaps you can tune up the lib to send the whole requests in the same time, which would be faster. Also, is the server on localhost? If it's not, a better network could also make a difference.

Comment: Was this really running for 1.5 hours?

Comment: @vyegorov The results are in msecs.

Comment: @Geoffroy In this case, the server was on my own machine. But it can be accessed remotely as well. It is on a 1Gpbs connection. And how do I need to tune the lib to send the whole request in same time? Any suggestions?

Comment: @c0da try to search for bulk insertion, that's what you want to do.

Comment: @Geoffroy 1 gigabit or 1 megabit, it doesn't matter much when small packets are involved; your main issue will be latency not throughput. You're sending each request, then waiting for a reply before doing more work. You can't do that efficiently; you need to be batching requests, have multiple in flight, etc. Pg doesn't support multiple concurrent requests (alas) but you can certainly batch, or in this case use `COPY` or multi-row inserts.

Answer (score 5):

On a TCP connection, each INSERT will cause a TCP round-trip to the database. 50000 inserts done in 5.5 seconds means that one TCP round-trip takes ~0.1ms. You'd have to compare that to TCP benchmarks with your network equipment, but probably you can't expect to go any faster with this method.

You should consider `COPY FROM STDIN` insteads of individual INSERTs. Internally, that will buffer the contents and you're likely to see a considerable speed increase due to much less round-trips to the server.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-copy.html for the libpq API related to this form of COPY.

Comment: If you can't use `COPY` you have the option of using a multi-row `INSERT` (ie: an insert with more than one tuple after `VALUES` eg `VALUES (1,2,3), (1,4,5), (1,9,1);`) to reduce round-trips. I assumed `libpq` supported batch operations like `PgJDBC` but I can't find any evidence of it, so maybe it doesn't! EnterpriseDB's libpq has a bulk send interface for arrays of data, but it isn't present in vanilla libpq.

Comment: c0da did you ever find a way to speed this up significantly?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and converted my series of inserts into one multi-row insert. Despite adding a lot of string mangling and strcat calls, this improved performance significantly:

```
1000 rows:
Individual Inserts: 22.609s
Multirow Insert: 1.217s
```

Code is at https://gist.github.com/Meekohi/11291680 (also shows example of inserting binary data into one column)